# Chrome extension - How to change text in page frames

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to write a chrome extension that changes a text on all frames on a webpage. I wrote the following code, but with it, I can only change the text on regular pages, not frames. Any idea how to do it?

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace('Hello', 'Hello2');

            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `"all_frames": true` in your manifest.json for content-script. (see [declaration](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration)).

Example:

```json
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```